# What is the preferred way to make a precision-changing Rails migration reversible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, precision, rollback

I have several tables with columns that were created with precision and scale specified. I need to create a migration to increase precision to accommodate new data that exceeds the previously defined values. I want that migration to be reversible, however, once the longer data values are entered in the database, rolling back those migrations will fail because MySQL will throw an "Out of range value for column..." error.

What is the preferred way to make a precision-changing migration reversible? For the time being (in development) I have the down method defining the same precision as the up method but is that the "right" way to handle this situation? Although that technically isn't a rollback, it does allow continuous rollbacks to prior migrations.

Comment: Since you are fine with the persisting the increased precision through the rollback this sounds like a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Id' say :

```
  def self.up
  MyTable.all.map{|x| do the stuff to ensure valid data}
  change_column :my_table, :my_field, :decimal, :precision => give whatever, :scale => give whatever
  
  end
  def self.down
   MyTable.all.map{|x| do the stuff to ensure valid data}
   change_column :my_table, :my_field, :decimal, :precision => give whatever, :scale => give whatever
  end
```

You can recalculate or reassing or mean or anythhing realy to ensure your needs.